# How can I run my own shell from elisp?

Tags: python, shell, emacs, elisp

I written a simple shell in python and compiled it with nuitka.
My shell as some simple commands, such as "say string", "braille string", "stop" etc.
This program uses python accessible_output package to communicate with screen reader in windows.
Ok, this works well froma a normal shell, or executing it from windows.
Now, I would like run this program from within emacs, such as normal shell in emacs.
I tried some functions, "start-process", "shell-command", but I can't write commands.
My program displays a prompt, like python interpreter, where I can put my commands.
Elisp is able to run python shells, mysql shells, but I'm unable to run my own shell.
Help!

Comment: Have you tried something simple, like `(start-process "my-process-name" nil "/path/to/script")`?  I used `nil` for the second argument because I'm assuming you don't need to see an output buffer in Emacs.  You can just evaluate it to try it out: `M-x eval-expression RET (start-process "my-process-name" nil "/path/to/script") RET`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emacs has a number of different ways to interact with external program. From your text, I suspect you need to look at comint in the emacs manual and the elisp reference manual. Comint is the low level general shell in a buffer functionality (it is what shell mode uses).

Reading between the lines of your post, I would also suggest you have a look at emacspeak. and speechd.el, both of which are both packages which add speech to emacs. Speechd.el is bare bones and uses speech-dispatcher while emacspeak is very feature rich. The emacspeak package uses a Tcl script which communicates with hardware or software speech servers. It also has a mac version written in python which communicates with the OSX accessiblity (voiceOver) subsystem. Looking at how these packages work will likely give you good examples on how to make yours do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how it's done in the nodejs-repl https://github.com/abicky/nodejs-repl.el/blob/develop/nodejs-repl.el (see line 308)

Answer (score 0):

In python-mode.el, the part in question reads

```
(with-current-buffer
(apply #'make-comint-in-buffer executable py-buffer-name executable nil (split-string-and-unquote args))
```

See docstring of `make-comint-in-buffer` for details.

Answer (score 0):

What about just launching your script from inside an emacs shell buffer?

`M-x shell RET /path/to/my/script RET`